# Wrapping Chars into_iter()

Tags: rust, iterator, char, lifetime

I have this simple `struct`:

```rust
struct MyStruct {
    text: String,
}
```

And want to implement the `IntoIterator` trait for it. Since `Chars` already implements it, I just want to wrap it:

```rust
impl IntoIterator for MyStruct {
    type Item = char;
    type IntoIter = std::str::Chars;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        self.text.chars().into_iter()
    }
}
```

This results in `missing lifetime specifier` errors since `Chars` needs a lifetime specifier.

I was able to solve this by implementing my own iterator. But I wonder if it is possible  just to wrap the iterator of `Chars`.

Comment: The `into_iter()` is unecessarty, `Chars` is already an iterator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can implement it for a reference to your type instead:

```rust
impl<'a> IntoIterator for &'a MyStruct {
    type Item = char;
    type IntoIter = std::str::Chars<'a>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        self.text.chars()
    }
}
```

There's no other way to achieve it without a custom `OwnedChars`, since `IntoIter` must own the `String` in your struct, but `Chars` can only hold an `&str`.